# "Olá, Fulano," ou "Olá Fulano," no começo de e-mails

Tags: vírgula

Sempre escrevi da primeira forma, mas tenho reparado que todo o resto da internet que me manda e-mails tem escrito da segunda maneira.

Qual é o correto? Ambos são aceitos?

Se o primeiro é correto, como eu espero, o que explica tanta gente (inclusive empresas grandes) escreverem da segunda maneira?

Comment: "ambos são **[aceites](http://priberam.pt/dlpo/Conjugar/aceitar)**" (Talvez "aceitados"? Não tenho a certeza.)

Comment: @ANeves Nunca tinha ouvido 'aceite' como particípio de 'acertar'...vou manter 'aceito' porque é o que estou acostumada e aparece entre as variantes do particípio de todo modo.

Comment: Eu não tinha a certeza, por isso é que deixei um comentário em vez de editar. :) Abri uma pergunta sobre isso, que te pode interessar: http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1231/pode-se-escrever-ambos-s%c3%a3o-aceitos

Comment: A última pergunta é off-topic tanto por ser primarily opinion based, como não tratar de língua portuguesa intrinsecamente. Ainda assim deixo a minha resposta a esta pergunta abaixo e apago-a noutro dia. Sugiro que a pergunta seja editada de forma a ser 100% on-topic.

Comment: Ambos são "aceitos" (pt-BR). :)

Comment: Aceitos. E: não tinha certeza, não a certeza. A certeza precisa ter algo depois: a certeza da verdade.

Comment: Atenção: em português de Portugal as palavras "aceitos" e "aceitas" simplesmente não exitem. Seria um erro ortográfico e gramatical. Da experiência que tenho só no Brasil é que a palavras "aceitos" ou "aceitas" é normalizada. Nos restantes Países de Língua Oficial Portuguesa, a forma correcta é: aceites, ou no singular aceite.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Segundo a gramática **normativa**, a forma correta [é a primeira](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/saudacao-vocativo-virgula/26534): “Olá, Fulano” (com vírgula).

“Olá” é uma interjeição de chamamento, e “Fulano” é um [vocativo](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno/portugues/definicao/vocativo.html). Uma das funções da vírgula é separar a interjeição do vocativo, e por isso deve-se inserir uma vírgula entre eles.

Comment: Me sinto melhor agora, porque não me lembro a última vez em que recebi um e-mail escrito com as duas vírgulas e estava começando a achar que o problema fosse comigo.

Answer (score 12):

Olá, Carla.

A forma correta é utilizar vírgula entre a interjeição de chamamento e o vocativo, mas não somente. A saudação deve terminar sempre com ponto final (.) e não vírgula (,). A saudação é uma frase por si só, e deve ser finalizada com ponto final. Seguem algumas referências:

http://portugues.uol.com.br/gramatica/vocativo-uma-questao-virgula.html

[http://www.tracto.com.br/ola-fulano-com-virgula-ou-sem-virgula](https://web.archive.org/web/20170108093158/www.tracto.com.br/ola-fulano-com-virgula-ou-sem-virgula)

Answer (score 10):

A forma normativa é com o uso de vírgulas, como o Bruno explicou, porque "olá" formalmente é uma interjeição, assim como "ei", "oi". Dessa forma,

```
Olá, Carlos,
```

Passa a ideia que emissor clama por atenção e então endereçasse de quem a atenção é requerida. Mesmo caso para outras interjeições como "saudações" (o emissor diz saudar alguém e o vocativo endereça a quem é a saudação).

Em inglês, um fenômeno que postulo ser semelhante ao que ocorre no português a interjeição "hello" vem mudando com o uso, perdendo a pausa com o vocativo. Essa proximidade pode ser visto como a transformação da interjeição em verbo. Nesse caso, não existiria a vírgula. Mas é bom lembrar que a gramática é resistente a mudanças como essa.

Answer (score 6):

A resposta à primeira pergunta é bem conhecida e já foi dada. Vocativo requer vírgula.

> Se o primeiro é correto, como eu espero, o que explica tanta gente (inclusive empresas grandes) escreverem da segunda maneira?

Na minha opinião isto é consequência da prática errada que é traduzir pausas (respetivamente falta delas) na língua falada, para o uso de pontuação (respetivamente omissão desta) na sintaxe.

Quando se fala "Olá fulano", não há nenhuma pausa, o que leva as pessoas a entregarem-se à prática errada descrita acima.

Como explicar que empresas grandes cometam este erro? Não sei, mas em legendagens e afins já vi erros mais graves, como por exemplo "Bébé" no telejornal da SIC (mais que uma vez). Isto leva a crer que simplesmente não há uma preocupação grande em escrever corretamente.

Comment: Eu até acho que normalmente há pausa em "olá, Vera" . Mas suponhamos que não há. Então a regra que manda lá pôr a vírgula é completamente arbitrária? Porque a utilidade da pontuação é precisamente traduzir na escrita a entoação e pausas.

Comment: @Jacinto Não completamente, é um engenho que funciona muitas vezes, mas não sempre. Diria que é um erro que se alastra desde a escola primária e que acaba por não ser corrigido, mas falo sem conhecimento de causa. Aquilo a que me comprometo é que sintaxe (e a vírgula é uma entidade sintática) e linguagem falada são línguagens com capacidades expressivas muito diferentes e nenhuma está contida na outra. Em particular, se aceitasses que não há pausa neste caso, isto seria um exemplo desta diferença entre a capacidade expressiva   destas duas linguagens.

Comment: Quanto ao edit do comentário, eu discordo que a utilidade da pontuação seja *precisamente* traduzir na escrita a entoação e pausas. A pontuação tem mais utilidade que isto. Ao falar, não há diferença entre vírgula, ponto final ou até um parágrafo. Não se faria uma pausa maior num parágrafo, (se existisse tal besta no discurso falado).

Comment: @GitGud eu faria uma pausa maior num parágrafo que num ponto final, e maior num ponto final que numa vírgula. :) Mas sim, concordo que a utilidade da pontuação não é *precisamente* traduzir entoação e pausas; isso é *apenas* uma das suas funções, entre outras (que algumas vezes são mutuamente exclusivas, e outras vezes não).

Comment: Para ver se eu vos consigo compreender, dão-me um exemplo de uma frase com um vírgula que exprima qualquer coisa na escrita mas não se traduza em nada na fala? Para clarificar, eu estou a pensar apenas em escrita com as vinte e seis letras e a pontuação. Concordo, claro, que outros símbolos oferecem possibilidades na escrita que poderão ser difíceis de transmitir na fala. E já agora, em "olá, Vera," admitindo que não há pausa, o que é que a vírgula exprime? Git Gud disse isso seria um exemplo da diferença das capacidades expressivas da fala e da escrita.

Comment: @Jacinto Com vírgula não me ocorre nada a não ser mesmo quando se usa vírgula e não há pausa a falar. Quanto à última pergunta, penso que a vírgula não exprime nada, em particular não exprime pausa (sob a hipótese de não haver pausa na fala), não é mais que uma entidade sintática que nada modela no discurso falado.

Comment: @GitGud A minha questão era precisamente o que é que a vírgula em "olá, Vera" exprime na escrita (admitindo que não há pausa). Como escreveste que a vírgula, neste caso, "seria um exemplo desta diferença entre a capacidade expressiva destas duas linguagens". Mas parece-me que afinal não exprime nada. Quanto à questão secundária da pausa compara os sons de _olá, Vera_ e _dá o anzol à Vera_. Há no lugar da vírgula qualquer coisa na fala, ou pausa ou inflexão de tom (tens que desculpar a imprecisão dos termo; sou um mero amador).

Comment: @GitGud Mas... descobri uma capacidade expressiva da escrita que a fala não tem: a _casa das silvas_ é diferente da _casa das Silvas_.

Comment: @Jacinto Também sou amador. Good catch a das silvas. Quanto à questão da vírgula, não exprime nada na fala, mas graficamente ela está lá, o símbolo de vírgula aparece na representação escrita da frase. Existe na escrita, mas não na fala, logo são diferentes.

Comment: E os carateres da palvra _amor_ também não aparecem na palavra falada. Mas não tenho nada contra quem se interesse por essas diferenças :)

Comment: Eu sempre digo "oi, fulano", com uma pausa entre "oi" e "fulano". E também sempre ouço as pessoas falarem assim. Aonde se diz "oi fulano" sem nenhuma pausa? Talvez em reuniões dos Alcoólicos Anônimos?

Comment: @LuísHenrique Procurei no YouTube por programas de televisão em que usem vocativo, mas não tive sorte, não achei nada. Se me encontrar um (preferencialmente mais) vídeo(s) em que haja uma pausa, agradeço.

Comment: @GitGud - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zfx5rtutpzo aqui, por exemplo, logo aos sete segundos. A pausa é claríssima.

Comment: Ela o é. Pensando no assunto, acho que quando o vocativo vem primeiro, é comum haver uma pausa, sim. Tendo em conta esta especificidade, peço então uma fonte em que o vocativo esteja no fim e haja pausa. Peço também desculpa por não ter pedido isto logo à partida, mas não me dei conta de que (na minha opinião) é normal haver pausa quando o vocativo bem primeiro, mas não quando vem depois.

Answer (score 0):

Interjeições devem ser separadas de vocativos por vírgula, portanto, o correto é:

```
Olá, fulano
```

Quando escrevo um e-mail, às vezes me parece estranho que a primeira linha termine sem pontuação e **"Olá, fulano."** me parece seco demais. Então, geralmente eu já aproveito e emendo com uma pergunta:

```
Olá, fulano, como vai?
```

Depois, prossigo com o e-mail.

Comment: Segundo a regra normativa, não deveria ser: `Olá, fulano. Como vai?`

Comment: Eu preferiria assim:

"Olá, Fulano, ¿como vai?".