# Pode-se escrever "ambos são aceitos"?

Tags: forma-verbal

É correto escrever "ambos são aceitos"?

Numa pergunta neste site vi as seguintes frases:

> Qual é o correto? Ambos são aceitos?

Eu esperaria `ambos são aceites`, e essa é a forma a que estou habituado. Em algumas situações ouço também usar aceitado ("não tinha aceitado o pedido").
Mas o dicionário priberam lista não só "aceite" e "aceitado" como particípio passado de aceitar, mas também "aceitos"...

Comment: Muito curioso, já tinha ouvido falar de várias sutis diferenças entre PT-BR e PT-PT, mas essa é nova. :)

Comment: @carla e eis outra! "diferenças subtis"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pode sim usar-se essa forma e é correta.

No Brasil tanto se usa *aceitas* como *aceitos*, por exemplo:

> As respostas aceitas como certas.

ou

> Ambos os termos são aceitos na língua portuguesa.

Usa-se a concordância com o sujeito masculino e feminino.

Em Portugal usa-se *aceite* para os dois casos, masculino e feminino, por exemplo:

> As respostas aceites como certas.

ou

> Ambos os termos são aceites na língua portuguesa.

Qualquer uma destas três formas é correta. Como disse o @Mindwin e muito bem qualquer uma das formas pode ser usada em qualquer um dos países.

É preciso ainda ter em atenção que em Portugal também se usa *aceito* e *aceite* em outras situações:

> Eu aceito casar-me contigo.
>
> Aceita esta aliança que te dou como sinónimo do meu amor.

Sendo que neste caso estamos a usar o verbo aceitar e não os adjetivos.

Comment: Vale lembrar que as diferenças entre Portugal e Brasil são somente de costumes, pode-se usar (mesmo que soe estranho aos nativos) quaisquer das formas.

Comment: No teu último exemplo, trata-se de classe gramatical diferente dos demais exemplos, vale ressaltar isto. São conjugações do verbo aceitar (e não adjetivos), e não sofrem diferenças regionais.

Comment: @Mindwin eu sei disso, pensei que estava óbvio. Amanhã edito a resposta e adiciono mais informações. Estou no smartphone.

Comment: Por se tratar de sítio internacional onde vários usuários são aprendizes, fiz a observação. Vale sim enriquecer a resposta, sempre!

Comment: @Mindwin já fiz os dois reparos ;)

Answer (score 6):

De acordo com a dúvida linguística "[aceitado, aceite e aceito [Flexão verbal]](http://www.flip.pt/Duvidas-Linguisticas/Duvida-Linguistica.aspx?DID=5673)" no FLiP,
a forma "aceito" é válida mas mais comum no Brasil:

> Para além das formas aceitado e aceite, o verbo aceitar admite ainda aceito como forma irregular do particípio passado, apesar de esta forma ser mais usada no português do Brasil (ex.: as nossas propostas foram aceitas).

---

Leitura complementar:

- Dúvida "[particípio passado regular e irregular [Flexão verbal]](http://www.flip.pt/Duvidas-Linguisticas/Duvida-Linguistica.aspx?DID=1049)" no FLiP

Answer (score 4):

No Brasil usamos **"aceitado"** preferencialmente após o verbo "ter"

- "Ele já tinha **aceitado** a proposta quando..."

Usamos **"aceito"** como adjetivo -

- "É uma forma ortográfica **aceita** até os dias de hoje."

Aceito também é o verbo aceitar conjugado na primeira pessoa do singular do presente do indicativo.

- "Eu **aceito** a tua opinião."

"aceite", no Brasil, é o verbo aceitar na primeira e terceira pessoas do singular do presente do subjuntivo.  "que eu aceite, que tu aceites, que ele aceite." Nunca ouvi "aceite" como particípio passado.