# Vocativo antes da saudação?

Tags: gramática

Tenho visto, com mais e mais frequência, e-mails começando por "Fulano, bom dia".
Vale isso, Arnaldo?
Eu sempre achei que a única forma permitida era "Bom dia, Fulano". Sempre a saudação antes do vocativo.
É como dizer "Fulano, oi". Estranho, não?

Comment: Relacionada: https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1213/ol%C3%A1-fulano-ou-ol%C3%A1-fulano-no-come%C3%A7o-de-e-mails

Comment: @ValdeirPsr Obrigado, Valdeir, mas minha dúvida não é sobre a vírgula. Ia até mencionar isso na pergunta mas achei desnecessário. De qualquer forma seu link pode ajudar outras pessoas.

Comment: nunca escrevo bom dia, boa tarde em emails. Não saberia quando a pessoa irá ler isso, então, não me faz sentido. Nunca vi email escrito tbm desse jeito. A única explicação que tenho é para chamar a atenção, começando pelo nome. Acredito que gramaticalmente, não estaria errado.

Vamos para um exemplo:

Roberto,

Bom dia! Como está?

Queria te dizer que preciso da cópia da conta de luz para a renovação da carteira de motorista.... não vejo tão ruim...e acho que a informalidade do email tbm permite...

Comment: Meu caro amigo [ou nome], minha querida Amalia [ou amiga]. Bom dia e  oi passaram a ser "saudações" mas realmente não são. Mesmo assim sempre escrevo: Oi João, Olá Marta, Bom dia Zé Sempre sem vírgula.

Comment: Estranho, devido à raridade, mas gramaticalmente correto visto que a gramática do Português não tem regras claras e estritas para a posição sintática das palavras dentro de uma oração!

Comment: Acho que você pode escrever das duas maneiras. E vocativo? O terra amada, é vocativo. :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Olá, Fulano," ou "Olá Fulano," no começo de e-mails](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1213/ol%c3%a1-fulano-ou-ol%c3%a1-fulano-no-come%c3%a7o-de-e-mails)

Answer (score 1):

Eu sempre achei que **a única forma permitida** era "Bom dia, Fulano".

Não, **não precisamos de permissão** para falar/escrever certo ou errado. As regras gramaticais existem, mas elas são bem flexíveis na língua falada. Emails e mensagens de texto são frequentemente informais e tentam reproduzir nossa fala.  Portanto, não há uma posição correta para as palavras que compõem uma saudação em emails informais e na língua falada.

- Bom dia, João.
- Maria, minha querida.
- Roberto, olá.
- Alberto, meu camarada, como vai você?

  O "bom-dia" pode até vir no final do texto, como uma despedida.