# "Bom dia, João" , "Bom dia João," ou "Bom dia, João, " Recebo emails com estas diferentes pontuações . Qual a mais correta?

Tags: português-brasileiro, ortografia, português-europeu, email

"Bom dia, João"  , "Bom dia João," ou "Bom dia, João,  "

Recebo emails com estas diferentes pontuações . Qual a mais correta?

Comment: Possível duplicata [“Olá, Fulano,” ou “Olá Fulano,” no começo de e-mails](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/1213/2759)

Comment: Duplicado, mas, de qualquer forma, isto está relacionado com as regras do vocativo - a forma correta seria "Bom dia, João" (embora a colocação da segunda vírgula a seguir ao nome da pessoa seja opcional, creio)