# Minha dúvida é sobre como escrever corretamente uma frase

Tags: português-brasileiro, escrita

É correto escrever "olá pessoal." Sem vírgula?

Comment: Já tens sete respostas à tua pergunta em:  ["Olá, Fulano," ou "Olá Fulano," no começo de e-mails](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1213/ol%c3%a1-fulano-ou-ol%c3%a1-fulano-no-come%c3%a7o-de-e-mails)

Answer (score 1):

O vocativo precisa sempre vir entre vírgulas, exceto quanto inicia ou termina uma oração, casos em que a vírgula vem depois ou antes do vocativo, respectivamente. Portanto, o certo é *Olá, pessoal!*

Ver por exemplo [esta página](https://educacao.uol.com.br/disciplinas/portugues/vocativo-para-chamar-o-ouvinte.htm#:%7E:text=Sempre%2C%20sempre%20o%20vocativo%20aparece,ora%C3%A7%C3%A3o%2C%20usamos%20a%20v%C3%ADrgula%20antes.)